# Java Version not changing

Tags: java

I do not understand why java is always causing problems when having multiple versions on the same machine.

Here is a screenshot of what I did:

[image]

Why is it not changing? I set my JAVA_HOME to point to 8.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /etc/alternatives/java`

Comment: And you forgot to say, that "I had JENV install and it was blocking everything."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac
```

else try this [link](https://github.com/mohamedzajith/UbuntuSoftware/blob/master/Java%208%20install)

Comment: I think I found the error, I had JENV install and it was blocking everything. Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: @TrtTrt And the commands above resolve your problem?!

Comment: Where is the difference between `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and `sudo update-alternatives --set java …`? This answer makes no sense.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and this didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

As you commented:

> I had JENV install and it was blocking everything.

Open your `~/.bash_profile`

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and remove the lines below

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
```

and

```
export PATH="/home/<your_user_name>/.jenv/shims:${PATH}"
source "/home/<your_user_name>/.jenv/libexec/../completions/jenv.bash"
jenv rehash 2>/dev/null
export JENV_LOADED=1
unset JAVA_HOME
jenv() {
  typeset command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  enable-plugin|rehash|shell|shell-options)
    eval `jenv "sh-$command" "$@"`;;
  *)
    command jenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

Open a new terminal and start

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

again